# PhpStorm Switch "root" repository in git widget

Tags: git, phpstorm

I recently attached a new repository (versioning) to an existing project in PhpStorm.

Now, the git widget selected the "versioning" project and I can't figure out a way to switch it back to my main repository... When I open the widget, it list my "versioning" project branches on foreground and I have to hit Repositories > main_repository to access my main project branches.

There must be a way, or somebody having the same problem ?

[image: widget hover]

Answer (score 2):

Branch widget is displaying a branch that belongs to a file that is in focus/opened in editor.
It means that you have a file from `versioning` opened in Editor, if you open a file from `main_repository` then you will see a change in a branch name

Comment: Don't know how I didn't realize that earlier, thanks !